# Querying database using Entity Framework not working as intended

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the current table, named Reviews: (I confirmed this directly in sql)

```
Id  Name            Summary         Rating
1   Reviewer one    Review one.     2.5
1   Reviewer two    Review two.     1.5
1   Reviewer three  Review three.   3.9
```

I'm trying to get all 3 reviews using `id == 1` which is a foreign key but what happens is I get the first review 3 times:

```
Id  Name            Summary         Rating
1   Reviewer one    Review one.     2.5
1   Reviewer one    Review one.     2.5
1   Reviewer one    Review one.     2.5
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
public List<Review> GetReviewModels(int restaurantId)  //restaurantId is 1
{
    List<Review> reviews = new List<Review>();
    using (var db = new ReviewEntities())
    {
        reviews = db.Reviews.Where(e => e.id.Equals(restaurantId)).ToList();
    }
    return reviews;
}
```

And here's the review entity model:

```
public partial class Review
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }

    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `id` not the primary key?

Comment: No, in SQL it was defined as:  `id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY references Restaurants(id)`

Comment: So which field *is* the primary key?

Comment: There is no primary key, it's a table dependent on a separate `Restaurants` table.  Is that why I'm having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
reviews = db.Reviews.Where(e => e.id.Equals(restaurantId)).ToList();
```

to

```
reviews = db.Reviews.AsNoTracking().Where(e => e.id.Equals(restaurantId)).ToList();
```

fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your Table/Model Your Model Should look Like:

```
public partial class Review
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId {get;set;}

    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

And you will need to add this to your Sql:

```
ALTER TABLE Reviews
DROP CONSTRAINT /*Name of Id fied constraint here*/ 

-- on a side note, you may have to Drop foreign key depending on the way it is in the database

ALTER TABLE Reviews
ALTER COLUMN Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)

ALTER TABLE Reviews
ADD COLUMN RestrauntId INT NOT NULL /*you can make this null if you need*/ FOREIGN KEY FK_Reviews_TO_Restraunt REFERENCES Restraunt(Id)
```

Comment: That does work but there's another solution that doesn't require altering tables

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in other way. As Reviews table references Restaurant table id so Restaurant entity model will be having List Reviews so in order to fetch all reviews for restaurant id 1 the goes is: 
This is the Review Model class.

```
 public partial class Review
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }

   public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
 }
```

This is the Restaurant Model class

```
public partial class Restaurant
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  //Rest all other fields.

  //Foreign key relationship/ Navigation property
  public List<Reviews> Reviews {get;set;}
}
```

And the function code is as follows:

```
public List<Review> GetReviewModels(int restaurantId)  //restaurantId is 1
{
   List<Review> reviews = new List<Review>();
   using (var db = new RestaurantEntity())
   {
      reviews = db.Restaurant.Where(e => e.id==restaurantId).Select(x=> 
      x.Reviews).FirstOrDefault();
   }
   return reviews;
}
```